# icons not appearing on webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi this is my first post so I'll try my best with the specifics.

I created a webpage using bootstrap {wrap} and the icons appear when I load from my localhost. As soon as I upload it to my Just Host webserver the icons disappear and the error I get is:

GET http://deusoft.co.uk/icons/css/ionicons.min.css 404 (Not Found)

any ideas what may be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like that CSS file is missing from your server.

Comment: Check if the css file exist on your server.

Comment: Looks like the icons css hasn't been uploaded to the server, are you sure you uploaded all the files? If you are, check that you have them at that location.

Comment: Hey Yeah I'm positive it is in that location and I've just re-uploaded it to the server to make sure. As i said it work offline but not online.

Comment: Look at http://deusoft.co.uk/ where you are referencing the css stylesheet. The file is no uploaded to that URL (http://deusoft.co.uk/icons/css/ionicons.min.css). So either the path is incorrect (less likely) or the file was never uploaded (more likely).

Comment: Here is the code linking the file to the webpage:<link href="icons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: The file is deffinantly there I can view it and edit it from my server space. and I've linked the code to link the stylesheet but still no icons.

Comment: Finally fixed it... It's unusual but for some reason the server space doesn't like the folder name icons. so I renamed it to icon and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Add `../` before the path of an image.

```
<img src="../Images/emp-001.jpg" width="100" height="112">
```